# Linking Microsoft Access to Microsoft outlook

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

How can I link Microsoft Access to  Microsoft Outlook so as to generate reminders for deadlines in my Microsoft Access database?

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like this

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/162371, but I made some "improvements" to it to make it a little more functional if you are working with variables.

```
Function AddOutLookTask(reminderDateAndTime As Date, dueDate As Date)
     Dim appOutLook As Outlook.Application
     Dim taskOutLook As Outlook.TaskItem
     Set appOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
     Set taskOutLook = appOutLook.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
  With taskOutLook
      .Subject = "This is the subject of my task"
      .Body = "This is the body of my task."
      .ReminderSet = True
      .ReminderTime = reminderDateAndTime
      .dueDate = dueDate                                              
      .ReminderPlaySound = True
       'add the path to a .wav file on your computer.
      .ReminderSoundFile = "C:\Windows\media\Notify.wav"

     .Save
  End With
End Function
```

You can test it in the immediate window using the code below with raw numbers, variables, etc.   Be sure to include the Microsoft Outlook 8.0 or higher Object Library Reference or it will not work

```
?addOutlookTask(#6/10/2015 3:45PM#, #6/11/2015#)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be quiet easy, you need to link the Calender table to Access. Look at this link for more info : http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/email/linked/index.htm

Comment: Thankyou , appreciated !

Comment: You are welcome. If this has answered your question, you can vote the answer up (or confirm this as answer) so others can be benefited from this too. Good luck.

Comment: paul nothing there about generating alerts/reminders , which is infact my main problem.

Comment: Now that you have the Data, you will need to create Queries off these data (tables), so you will be able to get them sorted. What you basically want is data, now you have that. Now you will be creating Queries that will lookup to this table and **SELECT theData FROM theCalender WHERE theTimeFalls BETWEEN someTime AND someOtherTime;** Hope that makes sense.